# Parsing UTF8 JSON response from server

Tags: c#, .net, json, http, utf-8

I am facing a weird problem parsing a JSON response from my server. It has been working fine for the last months when getting the response **(with Content-Type: text/html)** this way:

```
string response = "";
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var postData = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
    var clientResult = await client.PostAsync(url, postData);
    if(clientResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = await clientResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
//Parse the response to a JObject...
```

But when receiving a response with **Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8** it throws an exception that **Content-Type is invalid**.

`Exception message: The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.`

So I changed this:

```
response = await clientResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

to this:

```
var raw_response = await clientResult.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw_response, 0, raw_response.Length);
```

Now I can get the response without no exceptions but when parsing it, it throws a parsing exception. While debugging I got this: (I changed the response to a shorter one for testing purposes)

```
var r1 = await clientResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var r2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await clientResult.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), 0, raw_response.Length);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Length: {0} - {1}", r1.Length, r1);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Length: {0} - {1}", r2.Length, r2);

//Output
Length: 38 - {"version":1,"specialword":"C\u00e3o"}
Length: 39 - {"version":1,"specialword":"C\u00e3o"}
```

The JSON response format seems correct in both cases but the length is different and I could't figured out why. When copying this to notepad++ to spot hidden characters a **?** appeared from nowhere.

```
Length: 38 - {"version":1,"specialword":"C\u00e3o"}
Length: 39 - ?{"version":1,"specialword":"C\u00e3o"}
```

This **?** is obviously throwing the parsing exception but I don't know why `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` is causing that.

I have been battling with this for the last hours and I really need some help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `text/html; charset=utf8` i am sorry for delay. I did a test again to be sure

Comment: @T.J.Crowder First char: FEFF

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I'm surprised that you're getting that behavior, I would have expected `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to have handled that for you.

What you're seeing, the character value `0xFEFF`, is a byte order mark ("BOM"). A BOM is unnecessary in UTF-8 because the byte order is not variable, but it *is* allowed, as a marker that the following text is encoded UTF-8. (The actual byte sequence is EF BB BF, but then when that's decoded in UTF-8, it becomes code point FEFF.)

<s>If you create your own [`UTF8Encoding` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.UTF8Encoding.aspx), you can tell it whether to include or exclude the BOM.</s> *(I think I'm mistaken about that, it may only control whether it includes one when* encoding *.)*

Alternately, you could explicitly test for that and remove the BOM if present, e.g.:

```
var r2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await clientResult.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), 0, raw_response.Length);
if (r2[0] == '\uFEFF') {
    r2 = r2.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: with a simple string replace? and if different characters like this appears in the future?

Comment: @letiagoalves: By definition, there is only one allowed BOM for UTF-8, the one you've encountered. I'd probably use `Substring` rather than `Replace`. The BOM will only occur as the first character. More about BOMs and unicode [here](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Comment: +1 thanks for your help. I used `TrimStart('\uFEFF');` instead