# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.ReadAsStringAsync() results in COMException HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: c#, php, uwp, httpclient

I have following C# code:

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://lu32kap.typo3.lrz.de/mensaapp/exportDB.php?mensa_id=all");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var content = response.Content;
if(content != null)
{
     string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      if (result != null)
      {
           tblock.Text = result;
      }
}
```

Every time I run it, I get a **COMException "HRESULT E_FAIL"**.
I was able to track it down partially. It's caused by the website I'm trying to get my data from because if I'm changing it to "https://www.google.de/" it works.

It's crashing at:

```
string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Nevertheless I need to get it to work with this website because it returns a, with PHP generated, json object.
Is there a way to fix this?

[The image behind this link shows the crash in VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQgVk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code locally and I end up getting this Exception

> The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read
>   content as string using an invalid character set.

And it looks like it is returning `UTF8`

> 'utf8' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a
>   custom encoding, see the documentation for the
>   Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

Can you ensure that the output on the server is in the correct format? Perhaps try this answer:
[Parsing UTF8 JSON response from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043128/parsing-utf8-json-response-from-server)

Comment: Yes finally! Thanks!! It was a problem with the encoding!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
It was a problem with the UTF8 encoding. I was able to build a small workaround.
Thanks to Glitch100!

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://lu32kap.typo3.lrz.de/mensaapp/exportDB.php?mensa_id=all");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        IHttpContent content = response.Content;
        if(content != null)
        {
            IBuffer buffer = await content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
            using (DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
            {
                string result = dataReader.ReadString(buffer.Length);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    tblock.Text = result;
                }
            }
        }
```